# The marginal likelihood of a fully-observed continuous time Markov chain

Tags: likelihood, markov-process, continuous-data

Say we have a fully observed trajectory $S$ from a CTMC.  For a generator/rate matrix $Q$, we place gamma priors $\mathrm{Gamma}(\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2})$ on the diagonals, and $\mathrm{Dirichlet}(\beta)$ priors on the instantaneous transition probabilities.  Is there any literature on how to calculate this marginal likelihood?
\begin{align}
p\left(S|\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\beta\right)=\int p(S|Q)p(Q|\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\beta)dQ
\end{align}
I know that in such a model,we have
\begin{align}
p(S|Q)=\prod_{i=1}^{N}\prod_{j=1}^{N}q_{ij}^{n_{ij}}e^{-q_{i}\tau_{i}}
\end{align}
where $q_{ij}$ are the non-diagonal elements of $Q$, $q_{i}$ are the diagonal elements, $\tau_{i}$ is the total duration in state $i$, $n_{ij}$ is the number of transitions between states $i$ and $j$, and $N$ is the number of states.  It seems like a tricky integral to handle.

How likely is it that this is even tractable?